# Fix items only horizontally or vertically in the same scroll container

Tags: html, css

I need to build a tv guide like this one:

[image: TV Guide]

- If the user scrolls horizontally in the guide, the timebar should scroll but the channel list should stay fixed.
- If the user scrolls vertically in the guide, the timebar should stay fixed but the channel list should scroll.

Is this possible with only using CSS? I'd rather not use JS to solve this because of the performance.

I tried to make 2 scroll containers, 1 horizontal and 1 vertical, but I am only able to get 1 of the prerequisites right.
Here's the CodePen: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJbEJK)

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.page {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.horscroll {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.timebar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 5000px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.vertscroll {
  width: 5000px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.channel-list {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 10000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.content {
  width: 5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="horscroll">
    <div class="timebar">timeline</div>
    <div class="vertscroll">
      <div class="channel-list">channel list</div>
      <div class="content">grid</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you guys help me?

Many thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I also need a solution without position sticky since this is not supported in IE. The answer by Maharkus below is correct but it does not work in IE.

Comment: Why have you added a javascript tag to your question if you dont want it in javascript. This will simply draw in javascript programmers?

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example of how something like this could work. I used `position:sticky` for the scrolling which allows for the content to scroll while the bar itself is fixed in position:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.timeline {
  background: grey;
  height: 60px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.grid {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ffffff, #000000);
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
}

.channellist {
  height: 100%;
  background: darkgrey;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="timeline">Timeline</div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="channellist">
    Channellist
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx this indeed works, but position sticky is not supported in IE. Is there a way to solve this that works in every browser?

Comment: Well, I can't really think of another CSS only way to do this sadly. To be honest, I don't support IE in the work I do anymore ha. I think you won't get around using a few lines of JS for this one.

Comment: You're a lucky fellow :p I still have to support IE unfortunately. Thanks for the effort!